# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (Google Chart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization, require

I'm new to `require.js`.
I'm trying to display Google Pie Chart.
I be able to get it working in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/w0b73dwt/2/show).

[image]

---

## Issue

Then, when I move them into my real project, it doesn't work.
My real project using `require.js`

In my path, I declare it like this

`'piechart'            : 'reports/section-exercise/piechart',`

In my `piechart.js` , I have it like this :

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery' ], function ($) {

  $(function () {

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['l', 23],
        ['m', 30],
        ['h', 47],

        ]);

      var options = {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        chartArea: {
          left: 10,
          top: 20,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        },
        colors: ['#F46E4E', '#ADB55E', '#F9C262'],
        legend: 'none',
        enableInteractivity: false,
        pieSliceText: 'none',

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  });

});
```

---

## include

I included this link on top of my HTML file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={%27modules%27:[{%27name%27:%27visualization%27,%27version%27:%271.1%27,%27packages%27:[%27corechart%27]}]}">
```

---

## Result

[image]

---

## Error Message

[image]

Then, when I clicked on the file on the right, it re-direct me to this line :

[image]

---

How do I stop that error and make my chart display again ?

How is my include link ? I used the same one in JSFiddle as **external resources** and it works.

Comment: Well, your included link that you've shown us is a CSS stylesheet, not a script

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks for pointing out. Let me try to fix it now.

Comment: Actually, looking at the file, it *is* javascript, but you put it in a `link` tag.  Make it `<script src="url"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include that URL as JavaScript, but you're including it as CSS.  You need this:

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

rather than this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">
```